# vscode warning on first arguments being unused, but I use later arguments

Tags: node.js, express, visual-studio-code

Here's some basic code from express generator:

```
// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(request, response, next) {
    next(createError(404))
})
```

vscode complains:

> 'request' is declared but its value is never read.

I understand the warning, and that vscode wants me to remove unused arguments. However since the arguments are positional, I'd no longer be able to use `next` if I also removed `request`.

Is there a way to make vscode not warn about this, and still have thee route work?

Comment: Could you please tell me what are the files in .vscode folder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just prefix the unused argument names with underscores:

```
app.use(function(_request, _response, next) {
    next(createError(404))
})
```

VS Code's built-in unused variable checking will now ignore arguments that start with `_`